# How to use Substring , to return an integer of all the values after the first char

Tags: c#

I have an string AssetNumber that have the following format C100200.
so i need to do the folloiwng:-

1. Get all the characters after the first (e.g. 100200 using above example)
2. Convert the substring to integer
3. Return the integer + 1

but I do not know how to use the sub-string to get all the characters after the first char, and how to convert string into int? Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: what do u mean by this ,, can u explain please ?

Comment: @Shadow - Point taken..

Answer (score 8):

```
var result = Int32.Parse("C100200".Substring(1)) + 1;
```

If you would like to have default value, if you can't parse current string:

```
int result;
if (!Int32.TryParse("sdfsdf".Substring(1), out result)) {
    result = 42;
}

result+=1;
```

Comment: thanks , but how i can define a defualt values incase the string list is empty?

Comment: Updated for your default value case

Comment: By the way, no- when you use TryParse and couldn't do it- `result` get `0` value

Comment: I mean is there a way to mention that in case the result return 0, to make the default as 1000. so the 1000 become my starting number ?

Comment: `result = 999;` and you get what you want